# Pivot Table Source Data in Separate Excel Workbook stored on sharepoint

Tags: excel-services, business-intelligence, pivot-tables

I have an excel spreadsheet on the sharepoint server with my Main Data that I want to analyze. I want to make a pivot table from this sheet that will update when the Main Data is updated, but I need it in a separate excel workbook instead of in a sheet in the same workbook. The pivot table will also be stored on SharePoint.

I have tried to do this, but I get an error message saying `the source data cannot be retrieved`, and therefore the pivot table will not update. Is there a way to make this work? Or is this not possible to link the pivot table to source data stored in a separate document on sharepoint? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is the dataconnection from which the pivot content and the main data is coming from. in general the data can be any external sources or even SharePoint list but will not be another excel.

check the dataconnection settings with in the properties of the excel file from the pivot gallary to make sure it is a proper repository.

This should fix the issue.